# WCF classes not reflecting

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service for my project one of the classes in the service is not reflecting when i add the WCF service to my project, though the class is marked as  `<DataContract(), Serializable()> _`

kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand it, but if im right you should add that class as a ServiceKnownType:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554667.aspx